# What are mobile performance implications of scaling web viewport vs. canvas elements?

Tags: html, html5-canvas, css-position

I have an app that mixes DOM, SVG, and <canvas> elements for the GUI, and am wondering about the implications of different approaches to scaling.

I'm wanting to find a good strategy for scaling the app's layout such that:

1. The app is sized to a fixed aspect-ratio (say, 4x3) and maximized for the device, so "letterboxed" and centered horizontally or vertically.
2. Application code is as clean as possible. Ideally this means application code could assume a logical overall size (e.g. 1024x768).
3. Any needed scaling is applied in a way that does not negatively impact GPU performance.

The tricky bit is that <canvas> elements are rasterized, whereas all other parts scale fairly seamlessly independent of device resolution. Scaling the full viewport means the former will be scaled in a way that makes them fuzzy, and I believe impacts rendering performance (correct?). However the alternative is to calculate the dimensions of <canvas> at runtime, which means more complex code for drawing objects, and also variable memory use for graphics buffers. I don't believe it's a fair assumption that a device with twice the resolution can handle twice as much pixel pushing with equivalent performance.

As an example, assume the app wants to be in landscape mode with a logical size of 1024x768, and the device is 1600x1280. Since the logical has an aspect of 0.75 and the physical is 0.80, this would require vertical letterboxing, or scaling the height of the app by 1600/1024 = 1.5625.

**First approach, scaling the viewport**

```
var viewport = document.querySelector('meta[name=viewport]');
var scale = [ calculate ... ];
viewport.setAttribute('content', 'width=device-width, initial-scale='+scale+', maximum-scale='+scale+', user-scalable=0');
```

- **PRO** Positioning is as expected.
- **PRO** Minimal code in the app; can assume logical coordinates/dimensions everywhere.
- **CON** Canvas elements are fuzzy or pixelated. May impact canvas performance?

**Second approach, calculate the scaling and use this to calculate logical dimensions**

Keep the viewport scale at 1.0, but adjust any "pixel" values, as well as <canvas> dimensions, accordingly. So for example a canvas that wants to be half the width of the app would be sized as (logical 1024) / 2 * (scale factor 1.5) = 768.

- **PRO** Canvas elements are using device resolution (or 1/2 in case of retina/HD displays).
- **CON** Canvas elements use variable amounts of memory, which may not scale well for performance.
- **CON** Styling is required on the `body` tag to scale text; this in turn seems like a can of worms as to how it impacts static/relative positioned nested elements.
- **CON** Code needs to pass scale factors or dynamically calculated coordinates/dimensions to all drawing commands in canvas elements.

I'm unclear on how CSS em units play into all this. Fonts want to be sized in ems, but elements with font sizes in ems change the scaling of child elements, and I'd rather not end up wrestling with how this interacts with the "global" scaling. But maybe in practice this doesn't matter?

Any suggestions for a solid overall approach?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how i would do :
• Use a virtual resolution (you seem to call it logical size) for your canvas.
So your drawings are done once and for all in that virtual resolution (!issue closed!).
• Decide the real resolution = pixel size of the canvas (canvas.width =..., canvas.height). 
Notice that you should respect aspect ratio of virtual resolution.
• Decide the css size of the canvas. You must also respect aspect ratio here.
• decide of the way scaling/css scaling should be done ('crisp', ...)
• css scale the canvas so that it fits its css size. (canvas.style.width=...).
(Be sure to scale by the same ratio on x/y.)
• transform scale (context.scale(sc,sc)) the canvas so it fits its virtual resolution.
(Be sure to scale the same by the same ratio on x/y.)

I've written a small lib (SmartCanvas), that does just that, unfortunately it's written in Dart so i guess you wouldn't be interested.  When changing the parameters 'live' i saw that, on a big screen (1920X1200) i need to css scale X2 to have decent fps (>40).

In fact the tricky part for you will be to decide of the real canvas resolution. Css scaling has a cost, but to give a vague idea, upscaling X2 with css uses 25% of the performance required to draw at X2 resolution.
Only way i see to avoid headaches is to split all cases into a few ones, and test to see what's fit. For instance : 1) mobile  2) desktop < 1MPx  3) Desktop >1 MPx.
(you might also want to handle hiDpi cases).